# How much height the browser sets?

Tags: html, css, browser, height

Markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table width="500" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="background-color:#FFA500;">
                     <h1>Main Title of Web Page</h1>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:#FFD700;width:100px;"> <b>Menu</b>
                    <br>HTML
                    <br>CSS
                    <br>JavaScript</td>
                <td style="background-color:#eeeeee;height:200px;width:400px;">Content goes here</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="background-color:#FFA500;text-align:center;">Copyright ? W3Schools.com</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the html, there are no definitions about the height of top line and bottom line. How much height the browser sets?

[image]

Comment: Don't use tables for layout.

Comment: Press `F12` to open developer tools, and select the `computed` tab. Select any element and it will show you the computed dimensions.

Comment: if the html is in the firefox ,how can i see such the same thing  as in chrome ?

Comment: @it_is_a_literature: In firefox, I think you can use `firebug`, but the screenshot you provided looks like Chrome !!

Answer (score 0):

Using tables will cause lot of problems as each browser treats tables in its own way. You have to reset the browser default styles and style the table manually. Instead use it without tables.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id='header'><h1>Main Title of Web Page</h1></div>
    <div id='sideBar'>
      <ul>
        <li>Menu</li>
        <li>HTML</li>
        <li>CSS</li>
        <li>Other</li>
      </ul>
    <div id='pageContainer'>
      <h2>Content goes here</h2>
    </div>
    <div id='footer'>Copyright ? W3Schools.com</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now you can style it in css as per your need.

Comment: The way how different browsers style the table is not really the problem. Also lists, headlines, form elements, ... are styled differently. That's why various kind of css_reset_ files exists, that are included before the own css to have a common look. But you should not use tables for non tabular data.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question in the simplest way...a browser sets the dimension of view-port according to the content of the page, if nothing has been defined explicitly... [**see this**](http://jsfiddle.net/R23X9/1/)

```
<div>This is atext</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    /* height:100%;
    width:100%; */
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div {
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

**But** once the demension has been set in `html,body`...it takes up the width mentioned [**see again here**](http://jsfiddle.net/R23X9/2/)

```
html, body {
    height:100%; /*defined*/
    width:100%; /*defined*/ 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div {
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```